# Sum of two Beta distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I want to establish (although  I am not certain that it is possible to do so) that, if X,Y  with

$X \sim Beta(\alpha_1, 1- \alpha_1)$

$Y \sim Beta(\alpha_2, 1- \alpha_2)$

then

$X+Y \sim Beta(\alpha_1+\alpha_2, 1-\alpha_1-\alpha_2)$

With the convolution I have:

$
\int_0^1f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx
$
$
=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(\alpha_1,1-\alpha_1)}\cdot(z-x)^{\alpha_1-1}\cdot(1-z+x)^{-\alpha_1}\frac{1}{B(\alpha_2,1-\alpha_2)}\cdot x^{\alpha_2-1}\cdot(1-x)^{-\alpha_2}
$
$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)\Gamma(1-\alpha_1)\Gamma(1-\alpha_2)}\int_0^1 \cdot(z-x)^{\alpha_1-1}\cdot(1-z+x)^{-\alpha_1}\cdot x^{\alpha_2-1}\cdot(1-x)^{-\alpha_2}
$

I dont see how to continue here.
Any ideas are appreciated!

Kind Regards 
Humboldt

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are not i.i.d. random variables, I think this is going to be difficult.

Comment: They are i.i.d. I tried to use convolution, but failed rearranging the terms or calculating the integral

Comment: They are not identically distributed if $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$. Just a quick search brought me to [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00362-005-0273-8). The paper might be useful, or any of the references therein.

Comment: Thanks for the search, it did however not help me. The paper takes a look at the generalised beta distribution and the solutions are series. I would like to have a simple analytical solution. I thought this might be possible.

Comment: The sum of two Beta rv's is not going to be a Beta rv. There are some examples at: http://www.mathstatica.com/Sumof2Betas/

Comment: There is actually a fun thread on this question ... tackled using a number of different computer packages ... from the old usenet days (in 2004), for those who remember usenet. Several of the same people are now on stack exchange :) The thread is here:  http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.stat/JKq_k_A2GOc

Comment: The values of a Beta distributed rv ar a.s in [0,1]. If you add two independent  Beta-s you will get a random variable that, with positive probability takes values $>1$.

Answer (score 13):

The flaw in the claim is made apparent by simply considering the support of $X$, $Y$, and the sum $X+Y$:  since $X, Y \in [0,1]$, $X+Y \in [0,2]$ and that is very clearly not Beta distributed no matter what the underlying parameters might be.

Comment: Sure, but what about the mean?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104291/17941 for pointers to exact answers about sum of beta rv.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some simulations of sums of beta rv's, independent but not identically distributed, for some parameter values that seem reasonable for practical estimates of PERT parameters (min, most likely, max, lambda) for project effort estimates.  Since the sum is bounded below by the sum of the mins and similarly for the maxes, it seems reasonable to conjecture that the distribution of the sum is approximately beta.  I find that the approximation is either fairly good or very good for a casual sample of summand distribution parameters.  I fit the approximating beta by doing a least-squares minimization on the PERT most-likely and lambda parameters with Excel Solver.  This technique is of practical value in doing Monte Carlo simulations of project cost.  The cost of a phase is the sum of a number of PERTs for the tasks, and the cost of the project is the sum of the PERT (beta) approximations for the phases.